How to create custom layout options for a post within a custom Wordpress theme?
Currently building myself a Wordpress theme and new to using PHP. Having worked with Wordpress CMS for a while now I am struggling to understand how custom layout options are added into a post editor page on Classic Editor?
Typically when creating a new project the default text box will be in place for a project description but underneath will be a button that says 'Add Content' or 'Add Layout' where the editor can choose from a selection of pre-made layouts such as 'Full width Image' or '2 Column Image'. When selecting one of these a new section is added where the editor can click a button called 'Add Image' which then opens the Media Directory for adding an image.
I've attached a screenshot showing how the very bottom of the post editor appears with a blank 'Full width image' option added.
Do I need to create a series of custom layout options within my single.php file? If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. I'm probably using the wrong terminology hence why i'm struggling to find answers.screenshot of example
Are the post custom layout options created via PHP and then pulled into the single.php file for the post editor page where the layout options can be added?

Wordpress templates have nothing to do with the content. For example you have 1 template aka default which you can determine is full width for example. Then create another template lets say page-sidebar.php which will use same content just having sidebar. So if that image is only for fullwidth you will call it only in the full width template etc.. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ Another way is using get_template_part funciton if you want to keep single template file with conditions etc..

Thank you for this. However, is that for creating different page layout types rather than layout options for building out the post page directly? I am speaking in regards to a portfolio website theme so therefore would need a selection of layout options in order to build out each of my case studies. Rather than separate post-page types. Or have I completely misunderstood?

Creating more than default single.php like single-sidebar or single-template2 or w/e will give you dropdown menu to select template. Another way is based on how complex your theme will be to have theme options where you set which template will be used for all posts. This will prevent each post to have different template. For that you will use get_template_part() function with conditions based on theme option to load the correct template. Depends on the case and how the theme author want it to be tbh.

Ahhh okay. Yes, I want all of my case study posts to use the same template file. Within that the editor (me) has a choice of adding different block options. So if I call the get_template_part() and create a series of these. For example 'Full Width Image' and '2 Column Image' then these should appear as per the screenshot I attached in my original question? So that will ultimately allow me to build out each case study with the template parts I need.

Welcome! Based on your screenshot, this looks a theme that contains pre-built block options using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). Does your site have ACF installed as a plugin? Where did your theme come from? Or these are simply pre defined Gutenberg patterns. get_template_part() doesn't show anything on the editor side. get_template_part() only pulls in the php file that will render the code on the front end.
